# Showing that $\sigma$-algebra is uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra with the property that whenever $A \in \mathcal{A}$ is nonempty, there exist $B$, $C \in \mathcal{A}$ with $B \cap C = \emptyset$, $B \cup C = A$, and neither $B$ nor $C$ is empty. How do I see that $\mathcal{A}$ is uncountable?

Comment: Well, just show that $\mathcal{A}$ is infinite (but this question was asked extremely recently, I seem to recall...).

Comment: First show that the property yields an infinite sequence of disjoint sets belonging to $\mathcal A$.  There are uncountably many unions of these sets, each of which is distinct and belonging to $\mathcal A$.

Comment: @ErickWong nice proof, it would be a great addition to the original post